# MySQL - Convert Month/Yr to Date Field

Tags: mysql

I have this text string that I need to convert to a date:

June 2012

It's okay if the data is always just "01"

What's best approach to changing that "June 2012" string into a date?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', 'June 2012'), '%d %M %Y');
```

Result:

```
2012-06-01
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1 ','June 2012'),'%d %M %Y');
```

so the pattern is

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1 ',$YOUR_DATE_STRING),'%d %M %Y');
```